# XmlSiteMapController parameterless public constructor

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I’m using the NuGet Package MvcSiteMapProvider MVC4.  When I run MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc.XmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes(routes); [using this method](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/07/MvcSiteMapProvider-40-a-test-drive), I’m getting the following error when I run localhostXXX/sitemap.xml

**[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc.XmlSiteMapController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]**

Ostensibly, MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc.IXmlSiteMapResultFactory xmlSiteMapResultFactory is null, but I don't know why (or frankly, what that means).

I've not messed with routes at all, but I have developed the site a bit.  I created a custom  version of the XmlSiteMapController and gave it the overloaded null XmlSiteMapController method to poke around, but I’m not familiar at all with IXmlSiteMapResultFactory and besides, why is it trying to call a null method in the first place?  And just to cover bases, I have uninstalled and reinstalled MvcSiteMapProvider MVC4.

Works fine on all my other sites... any ideas?

**EDIT*****

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        MyAPI.Controllers.CustomXmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes(routes);
```

Then just made a blank controller (for tracing) in there:

```
    public CustomXmlSiteMapController()
    {
    }
```

to go along with...

```
    public CustomXmlSiteMapController(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc.IXmlSiteMapResultFactory xmlSiteMapResultFactory)
    {
```

Comment: Are you using internal or external DI? Could you post any custom IControllerFactory or IDependencyResolver implementations you are using as well as the code that initializes them from Global.asax? The constructor relies on DI to function (whether internal or external), and the default DI configuration uses IControllerFactory.

Comment: BTW - The NuGet packages (both internal and external DI) already include the XmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes() method in the startup, there is no longer a need to add that line manually.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast reply, yeah I suspect this is just internal DI.  It’s pretty much an out of the box MVC4 internet application.  I’ve connected to a database and have a page or two, I really just think something got muddled.

Comment: I'll add the custom code to the question.

Comment: I am a bit confused. The error message you posted indicates you are using the built-in XmlSiteMapController, but you are posting code indicating you are using a custom one. Both are valid, but using a custom XmlSiteMapController with internal DI is not supported. For that you will need to use an external DI container. http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/11/mvcsitemapprovider-4-cache-configuration#upgrade-internal-to-external-di. Most of the time the built-in XmlSiteMapController will suffice.